# Deserialization error. permission matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django web app to heroku and I get the deserialization error whenever i run the command 'Heroku run python manage.py loaddata project_dump.json'. Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/hainhtat/carzone-github) of the project.
Here is the screenshot of the error.
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate` before your `loaddata` command? Migrations will create/insert any permissions

Comment: I did it on local but not yet on heroku. Can it affect?

Comment: I try heroku run python manage.py migrate. But I still have the error.